# Преобразовать список словарей с вложенным списком словарей при возможном отсутствии ключа python

Tags: python, словари, dict

Исходные данные на python:

```
lst = [
{'fruit': 'apple', 'types': [{'type':'green', 'amount':'2'},{'type':'red', 'amount':'3'}]},
{'fruit': 'melon', 'types': [{'type':'yellow', 'amount':'4'},{'type':'red', 'amount':'5'},{'type':'orange', 'amount':'1'}]}
]
```

нужно получить следующий словарь из списка `lst`:

```
dict = {'apple': {'green':'2','red':'3'},'melon': {'yellow':'4','red':'5','orange':'1'}}
```

в одном из предыдущих вопросов мне уже помогли со способом преобразования списка `lst` в нужный вид:

```
dict1 = {item['fruit']: {v['type']: v['amount'] for v in item['types']} for item in lst}
```

Однако некоторые вложенные словари в исходных данных `lst` могут не содержать в себе ключа `'amount'`, соответственно выдает ошибку: `KeyError: 'amount'`

Задача: дописать этот способ, чтобы он выдавал значение `'amount': None` внутри вложенного словаря, если не нашел значение по ключу `'amount'`, чтобы не было такой ошибки `KeyError: 'amount'`

Буду очень благодарен помощи!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо чуть доработать dict comprehebsion - воспользоваться методом `.get` для словарей, который подставляет в искомый ключ значение по умолчанию, если этот ключ отсутствует в словаре:

```
lst = [
{'fruit': 'apple', 'types': [{'type':'green', 'amount':'2'},{'type':'red', 'amount':'3'}]},
{'fruit': 'melon', 'types': [{'type':'yellow', 'amount':'4'},{'type':'red', 'amount':'5'},{'type':'orange', 'amount':'1'}]},
{'fruit': 'banana', 'types': [{'type':'green'},{'type':'red', 'amount':'3'}]},
]

dict1 = {item['fruit']: {v['type']: v.get('amount', "unknown") for v in item['types']} for item in lst}
print(dict1)
```

```
{'apple': {'green': '2', 'red': '3'}, 'melon': {'yellow': '4', 'red': '5', 'orange': '1'}, 'banana': {'green': 'unknown', 'red': '3'}}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! еще сопутствующий вопрос возник при решении этой задачи. Я применяю метод float(v['amount']) для конвертации количества в целое число. Но в некоторых исходных данных уже ключ amount есть, но значение по нему - '' (пустая строка), и появляется ошибка could not convert string to float: ''. Как заменить все пустые строки во вложенных словарях на 0?